# What does "long" mean in "Flying cars, long the dream of everyone in a traffic jam...."

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

I am reading [an article](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/personal-air-land-vehicle.htm); I am confused about this sentence:

> Flying cars, long the dream of everyone in a traffic jam and a basic mode of transportation for everyone on "The Jetsons," are another automotive dream.

I cannot understand why "long" could be put in front of "the dream." Could anyone please explain the grammar in this case?

Comment: It just means for a long time: Long have I dreamed of an automotive dream.  Oh, I used dreams twice, not a model of good writing.

Answer (score 3):

Long is an adverb here, meaning "for a long time."

An analogous construction using the more obvious adverb *recently* is *ice cream, recently the only dessert available in the restaurant, will soon be joined by other options including cake and custard.*